# My laptop screen is broken. What CLI commands can I try to activate my HDMI out, not knowing what my HDMI port is titled?

Tags: 18.04, display, hdmi, xrandr

My laptop screen is completely crushed and doesn't work. So, I don't know what my HDMI port is titled. What CLI commands can I try to get my system to display on my external monitor?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, with LXDE. The laptop is a common AMD/Radeon HP15 x64.

I've searched the forums for answers & tried a number of xrandr commands, but nothing's working...plus, I can't list my ports, so I'm just guessing what directions to give in the CLI.

Comment: Might try something like `xrandr --auto`, also, there is usually a dedicated button for the second monitor (fn+f4 in my case).

Comment: Tx...tried the super+p...no change...ext monitor still saying no signal...

Comment: No vga port, sadly. Xrandr --auto doesn't do anything. Function keys not doing it, either. So far, still can't get HDMI-to-monitor working.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the autocomplete feature that `xrandr` does provide in bash. If you have just one HDMI port, the chances of you start typing `HD` followed by tab to autocomplete, it will get the correct port.

So something like, replacing the `TAB` by actually pressing it and typing the rest:

```
xrandr --outpTAB HDTAB --auto
```

If that fails, try adding a 0 and maybe a 1 after pressing TAB to autocomplete the port name. If after doing all this, it still fails to display image on your TV, the likely culpirt is not the name of the port, but instead that `xrandr` might be choosing a output format that your TV does not support, so you might try to be more explicit on that, for example:

```
xrandr --outpTAB HDTAB --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

Again, experiment with the values, for example, try 1920x1080i, and different refresh rates on the `--rate`, and even omitting it initially. Also try tab autocomplete on those values.

Comment: TX for the answer...i tried all the autocomplete answers, but still no go, either...could be xrandr is broken...maybe it's possible to try mirroring...I'm about ready to give up, though...

Comment: When was the last time that you used the hdmi output of your laptop? Also, I'm not sure how much of the screen you can actually see, but have you tried installing `openssh-server` and sshing into the machine?

Comment: Your answer is probably excellent and there's something amiss with my hardware...for example, i haven't ever used the hdmi port, so that's possible...screen is totally unreadable, which complicates the matter, along with no vga...

Comment: I believe your best option to try and salvage it is to ssh. You can either install it directly, or place the hdd on another machine and install it there. Remember to enable password login. After that you can troubleshoot it more and see whether it would be worth to replace the screen, if there are other stuff broken, if you can use it simply remote, if you can manage to get the hdmi output working, etc.

Comment: I've no familiarity with ssh, so I'll do some reading...I only have this laptop...no other machines handy...kinda isolated here in "darkest Africa"....tx much for the assistance...

Comment: If you manage to install the `openssh-server` you can ssh into it even from your smartphone (I'm assuming that's where you are posting from). Take a look at Termux (both on F-Droid and Google Play Store). I believe `PasswordAuthentication` is enabled by default on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, so just installing the package might be enough. If you need any assistance, let me know. But you should indeed read more about ssh, if you haven't used it before, including on best security practices if you decide to leave ssh server on for the future.